# MySQL showing corresponding value in second column based on condition

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have table with data in following structure:

```
    CallNumber  | Duration
    1112            30
    1112            null
    1112            null
    1119            10
    1175            null
    1132            59
    1175            190
```

I want result of select query as:

```
    CallNumber  | Duration
    1112            30
    1112            30
    1112            30
    1119            10
    1175            190
    1132            59
    1175            190
```

I do not know how to achieve the above result I am using MySQL database.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: What happens if there are duplicates of a key?

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want `1112` to appear multiple times? Why not just the once?

Comment: what's the meaning of these null rows? Why are they there? What do they represent? And why do you want your output to pretend they actually had the value shown in another row for the same callnumber? This data doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. Don't you just want to exclude the null rows? Also, what have you researched and tried so far? There's not even any basic SQL attempt here?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the sql code:

```
select 
  t.CallNumber,
  if (Duration is null, (select Duration from test  where t.CallNumber = CallNumber and Duration is not null limit 1), Duration) as Duration 
from 
  test t
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to give an explanation to your suggested code